# Android Swagger client with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, swagger-codegen, signed-apk

I have generated Android swagger generation code and implemented into my Android Project. Its working fine in Debug mode, but when generated signed APK, API's are not working. Do I need to add in Proguard file to correct signed APK.